# Running Commands on a Remote Linux

Tags: ssh, remote

I use this command for remote server.

```
# now=`ssh root@192.168.137.137 -t uptime | awk '{ print $8  }'`
echo "$now"
```

I get "Connection to 192.168.137.137 closed." but i don't want show this message.
I want show only output command.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this goes to `stderr`, you can pipe it to `/dev/null`:

```
ssh root@192.168.137.137 -t uptime 2>/dev/null | awk '{ print $8 }'
```